# "to go forward" vs "to walk forward"

Tags: word-usage

Why does it sound more natural to say:

```
He stood up and started walking forward.
```

that

```
He stood up and went forward
```

The questiion is for difference between *to go* and *to walk*. Taken an attempt to find it in a dictionary, but haven't got any success.

Comment: To me, it depends on the context. And I am not sure if it's an on-topic question, since to me it is just asking for an opinion... Or rather you are stating your opinion in an interrogative and expecting folks to both agree with you and then explain why *you* find one expression more natural than another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, the verb "to go" meant "to walk", but it has come to mean a number of things in addition to walking.

*I go to the store frequently* does not necessarily mean that you walk there. You could drive there too.

*I go to school* can mean that you are a student.

*I went home* would mean only that you left and made your way back home by some means. One could not infer that you walked.

So, in situations where you want to refer specifically to walking, in order to make perfectly clear that you mean "walk", the word "walk" is simply clearer, not more natural, than "go".

How did you get home? Did you take a taxi? I walked.  ("I went" would be unnatural.)

DIRECTOR TO ACTOR: when she looks up, you go to her and put your arms around her.

Perfectly natural use of "go" to mean "walk over to".

DIRECTOR TO ACTOR: What did you do when she looked up? ACTOR: I went over to her.

Natural too.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not show the comparison between "to go" and "to walk". Instead, the examples you have provided talks more about 
the different tenses - "started walking" & "went".
"Started walking" -  past continuous just like "was walking"
"went" - past tense

The sentence "He stood up and started walking forward." sounds better because it follows the grammar pattern - He  and then  where "then" is latent.

Comment: Why *started walking* is Past Continuous? I believe *to start - started* is used in a Past Simple tense and then there is some unknown construction - verb + (verb + -ing)

Comment: The meaning implied is that of a past continuous.

Past continuous - He was walking OR He started walking.
Both denote that he was walking is past tense and walking itself is continuous tense.